# Standard deviation above maximum possible value

Tags: standard-deviation

I calculated a mean and the standard deviation for it. The mean it at 99%, the standard deviation is 5%. In case I plot that, the upper end of the standard deviation will be above 100% which is not possible in reality.
The following image shows an example:
[Barplot with SD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUqkj.png)

I have no idea how to handle this issue. Thank you

Comment: Show what you have done and then we probably can help you. It also helps to understand your question, which is not 100% clear at the moment.

Comment: By adding the standard deviation, I exceed the maximum possible value - so it is useless or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your question. For instance, what kind of distribution you are talking about? You can make an edit.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @callculus - I added the example

Comment: Did you calculate the standard deviation from the actual data or a model?

Comment: I calculated that from the data

Comment: Can you show me the data? I want to double-check the calculations.